# Discover all installed R packages with a Java dependency (for security reasons)

Tags: java, r, installation, package, rjava

For security reasons I am forced to de-install Java (JRE) on a machine I am using with R.

How can I (easily :-) discover all installed packages that use Java?

**Edit 14.12.2021:** The log4j-log4shell-cve-2021-44228-vulnerability makes this question (and answers) even more interesting ;-)

Comment: so you need to un-install a `jre` and all other software that might be using it?

Comment: Sorry for using the "java" tag, this is probably more an R question. Yes, but R is implemented mainly in C and most packages (libraries) in R, C and C++. I just want to de-install those R packages that call Java/JRE

Comment: ah! sorry can't help u here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `installed.packages` to determine which packages import the `rJava` package.  You need to tell `installed.packages` to include the `Imports` field from the package description, and then check which packages import `rJava`.

```
LIBS = installed.packages(fields=c("Imports"))
JPacks = grep("Java", LIBS[,"Imports"], ignore.case=TRUE)
LIBS[JPacks, c("Package", "Imports")]
          Package    
RWeka     "RWeka"    
RWekajars "RWekajars"
          Imports                                                                
RWeka     "RWekajars (>= 3.9.0), rJava (>= 0.6-3), graphics, stats,\nutils, grid"
RWekajars "rJava (>= 0.6-3)"
```

Comment: Great answer! Is `rJava` the only way for packages in R to use Java?

Comment: The only way that _I_ know of :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have extended the solution of @GSW's answer by also considering other types of dependencies from the `rJAva` package:

```
libs       = installed.packages()

imports    = grep("Java", libs[,"Imports"],   ignore.case=TRUE)
depends    = grep("Java", libs[,"Depends"],   ignore.case=TRUE)
linking.to = grep("Java", libs[,"LinkingTo"], ignore.case=TRUE)
enhances   = grep("Java", libs[,"Enhances"],  ignore.case=TRUE)
# SystemRequirements may also contain Java dependencies but is not available in the matrix

libs[c(imports, depends, linking.to, enhances),
     c("Package", "Imports", "Depends", "LinkingTo", "Enhances")]
```

This now also finds eg. `xlsx`:

```
         Package    Imports Depends           LinkingTo Enhances
xlsx     "xlsx"     NA      "rJava, xlsxjars" NA        NA      
xlsxjars "xlsxjars" NA      "rJava"           NA        NA
```

**Edit Dec 21, 2021:** If you want to find all CRAN packages (not only the installed ones) that directly depend on JAVA (eg. due to `log4j` vulnerability) you can use:

```
# Dependencies external to the R system should be listed in the `SystemRequirements` field of the package's DESCRIPTION file.
# This also holds true until the package uses Java via the rJava package where the `Imports` or `Depends` declaration suffices:
# https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Non_002dR-scripts-in-packages

CRAN.pkgs <- tools::CRAN_package_db()  # gets a list of all R packages at CRAN

imports    = grepl("Java", CRAN.pkgs$Imports,             ignore.case = TRUE)
depends    = grepl("Java", CRAN.pkgs$Depends,             ignore.case = TRUE)
linking.to = grepl("Java", CRAN.pkgs$LinkingTo,           ignore.case = TRUE)
enhances   = grepl("Java", CRAN.pkgs$Enhances,            ignore.case = TRUE)
sysreq     = grepl("Java", CRAN.pkgs$SystemRequirements,  ignore.case = TRUE)

CRAN.java.pkgs <- CRAN.pkgs[imports | depends | linking.to | enhances | sysreq,
                            c("Package", "Imports", "Depends", "LinkingTo", "Enhances", "SystemRequirements")]

NROW(CRAN.pkgs)         # more than 18.000 in 12/2021
NROW(CRAN.java.pkgs)    #              137 in 12/2021

CRAN.java.pkgs$Package  # show all packages found
```