# Are there r packages affected by the current log4j / CVE-2021-44228 security issue?

Tags: r, log4j, tidyverse

[RStudio has confirmed](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-is-not-affected-by-cve-2021-44228-log4j-vulnerability/124143) that it is not affected by the current log4j / [CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228) security issue. However, it has not become clear to me whether there might be any r packages with a log4j dependency. I'm most interested in the `tidyverse` package and other packages that are broadly used such as the `xlsx` package.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47582588/discover-all-installed-r-packages-with-a-java-dependency-for-security-reasons) a discussion on how to detect whether installed r packages have a Java dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Probably not**.

The only packages that would *a priori* be affected would be those that depend — directly or indirectly — on Java components, since the log4j vulnerability itself only affects Java code using the log4j Java pacakge.

Bob Rudis scanned for potential vulnerabilities in packages hosted on CRAN and [posted the results on the R-pkg-devel mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2021q4/007589.html):

> I've scanned all of CRAN with —
> https://github.com/mergebase/log4j-detector — (and looked for the
> log4j v2 jar directly) and it's all good […]
>
> The odds of any R environment being impacted by this vulnerability
> were super slim (to almost none) to begin with and — if the tool is
> accurate — it's 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can also verify with following script on any installation location:

```sh
find . -name '*.jar' | grep -i 'log4j-' | xargs grep 'JndiLookup'
```

after you identify the jars which are impacted, you can correct with following script:

```sh
find . -name 'log4j-core-2.[0-9].*jar' | while read dir;do zip -q -d $dir org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class; echo $dir ; done
```

Comment: That’ll miss projects which bundle dependencies inside a single JAR (because log4j will be part of a JAR without `log4j` in the name). Still, this is a good, automatic solution for scanning dependencies. One caveat, the second command will break if there’s whitespace or other funny (but legal) characters in the dir name. [Better to use `-print0` with `find` in these situations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612232/1968), and then adjust the `read` command accordingly (`IFS= read -r -d ''`.)

Comment: Thank you Konrad, yes you are right. This works only for jars which are started with log4j,  doesn't work even when log4j jars embedded in war file.